# How To Check Electrical Current

Tags: electrical, low-voltage

I believe the PSU in one of my gaming consoles is shot.  I was attempting to test the current using [Woods Analog Multimeter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/403246159817?chn=ps&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1oC-7FtmPTP6ByCGe2tcr8Q79&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=403246159817&targetid=1599090336897&device=c&mktype=&googleloc=9011071&poi=&campaignid=15275224983&mkgroupid=131097072938&rlsatarget=pla-1599090336897&abcId=9300697&merchantid=6334344&gclid=Cj0KCQjw3IqSBhCoARIsAMBkTb3GjnALWmfvuWCEHyoIxqfQDao3U8dJH7Sq-KRx5w1p1hxVLz7P1OMaAoLyEALw_wcB)

Will this tool do the job and tell me if the voltage from the PSU is within the appropriate range?  If not, can someone recommend a good one from a local box store that I can pick up?

Comment: yes `measure voltage` ... no `test the current` ... you have to know what you are doing to measure current

Comment: As jsotola said, that meter should be fine for measuring the voltage.  It can also measure current, but you have to know what you're doing to measure current in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure current you need to put a resistor in series with the PSU and its load. Then measure the voltage drop across the resistor, from this you can calculate the current using OHM's Law calculator. https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/electric/ohms-law-calculator.html Start with a DC voltage range as close to the PSU output as you can without going under. Place your meter leads on the resistor, if the meter goes backwards reverse the leads. Try to get a reading in the 1V range or less. If it is higher lower the resistor value, if lower raise the resistor value. Use this number along with the value of your resistor and go to the calculator, it will give you the current you are drawing.

Comment: Or you know, use a meter that measures current straight up, or a clamp meter that doesn't require modification of that device under test....

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend a digital multimeter. While analog meters can have advantages in certain situations, for typical consumer electronics use (like checking the voltage on a power supply) and general household use (like testing 120V and 240V receptacles), a decent digital multimeter is much easier to use. In particular, you don't have to try and focus on which scale applies to the current usage - you just read a number.

Almost anything will do for consumer electronics, but I'd recommend getting a decent quality CAT II (many are rated CAT III as well, which is even better) multimeter. That gives you a reasonable assurance of a safe design for use with 120V and 240V AC circuits. I have a [Klein MM300](https://amzn.to/3JRgyoN), which is rated CAT III:

[image: Klein MM300]

but there are plenty of other reputable brands, such as Fluke. But beware - Amazon has a "similar item" on the same page which is a piece of uncertified junk - flashy but meaningless "CE" but without the actually meaningful ETL (which the Klein has) or UL listing.

Comment: ohhh, my local box store has this in stock, i'm going to pick it up this afternoon.  What "notch" would I set it on to test...I I am hoping to get a reading of 11.93V +/- .03V

Comment: black probe in the middle, red probe on the right (that will be the case for most things you do), for DC V (which is the usual for output of computer power supplies), upper left - in your case 20 (because 12V > 2 and < 20). For AC V (household mains) you use the upper right. Manual should explain it all, but mostly you just need to remember what the symbols mean.

Comment: Yeah - that was what I was unsure of was what each symbol meant...haven't had a chance to hit the local box store yet unfortunately